# How can i let my choice save with PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql

Can someone please help me? I am a beginner in PHP and SQL and i want to give the  a value of the "client_code" which comes from the database (phpMyAdmin). That if i choose something in the dropdown that it will change it to the choice that i chose.

**PHP/SQL code**

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT name, client_code FROM client";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<option><?php echo "Naam: ".$row[0]. ", Code: ". $row[1];?></option>


<?php

}

?>

</select>

</form>
```

**Database example**

```
Client_code | Name
    1       | Daniel
    2       | Isaac
    3       | Marcus
    4       | Bob
    5       | Rick
```

If i choose Daniel from the dropdown i need the value to be the client_code so it will update it inside the main view page which shows only Client codes.

Thanks for your time and knowledge on this!

Comment: start by fixing the html, `option`, needs values, an opening `select` with a name is also required

Comment: @IdontDownVote Yes i understand that a little bit but i don't want it to be static, if there is a new "Client_code" and new "Name" it needs to catch that from the database and put it inside a option. If i knew how to fetch each number and put them in a html value and stay dynamic if a new row is added. Can you make an example in an answer for me please?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: you still have to populate the values, or noting will be posted in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="select_box">
    <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['Client_code']?>"><?=$row['Name']?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Note that phpMyAdmin is not a database.... Mysql is your database...

Comment: select should have a `name='XXXXX'`

Comment: I will try this, i will come back to you. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @IdontDownVote How does it work if i want to update it. with the value's. If i choose name i want the database to know that i changed it to "Daniel" which is client_code:1. And how does this work if i add more Clien't code's and names? How can i make it dynamic

Comment: @user10320039 your selecting all the db rows and putting each in an option, so if you add 10 more rows to the db, 10 more options will be displayed

Comment: I will try something, and will get back to you tomorrow. Thanks for your time